# How to draw polygon using hardcoded values in ngMap using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polygon, ng-map

I need to draw polygon on google maps using the hard coded values.I have used ngMap ( https://ngmap.github.io/ )and used drawing manager of ngMap to it, because i also want the user to draw polygon dynamically. if i use drawing manager,i am not able to draw polygon with hardcoded values. and also another thing , if the user put the marker on map. i need to get the co-ordinates of it. (for example:get the co-ordinates in alert box or console). can anyone please help me 
Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/keRsKthRAwX89WOWeYwZ?p=preview

```
<ng-map zoom="12" center="28.623457, 77.196452"
map-type-id="ROADMAP"
street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
<drawing-manager
  on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
  drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon','marker']}"
  drawingControl="true"
  drawingMode="null"
  rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
  circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}" >
</drawing-manager>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. How to draw a polygon**

To display a polygon use a `shape` directive with `name` attribute set to `polygon`:

```
<shape path="{{vm.paths}}"  name="polygon" ></shape>
```

**2. How to get a marker position via Google Maps Drawing Manager**

```
vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function (e) {
    if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        var pos = e.overlay.getPosition();  //get marker position
        alert(pos.toString());
    }
};
```

**Modified example**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('DrawingManagerCtrl', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.paths = "[[28.646359, 77.259623],[28.645153, 77.207438],[28.680098, 77.120921],[28.680098, 77.259623]]";


    vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function (e) {
        if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            var pos = e.overlay.getPosition();
            alert(pos.toString());
        }
    };
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm">
        <ng-map zoom="12" center="28.623457, 77.196452"
                map-type-id="ROADMAP"
                street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
            <drawing-manager on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
                             drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon','marker']}"
                             drawingControl="true"
                             drawingMode="null"
                             rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
                             circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}">
            </drawing-manager>


            <shape path="{{vm.paths}}"  name="polygon" ></shape>
        </ng-map>
</div>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6pAqcEbOR6lIumM43uXm?p=preview)