# Display an existing polygon while using draw mode of ngmap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I was able to do the same as [this](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!drawing-manager.html) example in order to let the user draw a polygon and it works perfectly. Now I want to display an existing polygon inside the same map. How can I do that?

To explain more: I have used the first example for the create mode in my `spring boot`/ `angularjs` application. For the edit mode, I want to display the polygon that the user already drawn and let him draw another one.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that using  `<shape path="{{vm.paths}}"  name="polygon" ></shape>` inside the `<ng-map>`. Thanks to the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631298/how-to-draw-polygon-using-hardcoded-values-in-ngmap-using-angularjs/34639120?noredirect=1#comment74643246_34639120) issu, this is how it's possible:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm">
        <ng-map zoom="12" center="28.623457, 77.196452"
                map-type-id="ROADMAP"
                street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
            <drawing-manager on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
                             drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon','marker']}"
                             drawingControl="true"
                             drawingMode="null"
                             rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
                             circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}">
            </drawing-manager>


            <shape path="{{vm.paths}}"  name="polygon" ></shape>
        </ng-map>
</div>
```